# How to avoid being decapitated by an executioner?

Tags: alice-madness-returns

I just encountered this monstrocity in Chapter 4, but have no idea how to defeat it. It seems to be immune to all the attack types (pepper grinder, teapot, vorpal blade and the wooden horse). I am stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to win against the Executioner - just evade his attacks for a time, and Alice will eventually get the chance to retreat.  He's going to continue chasing you, so plan to continue evading his attacks and fleeing from him when you encounter him again.

The [Alice Wikia](http://alice.wikia.com/wiki/Executioner) notes:

> The Executioner is completely invulnerable and the only means of keeping him at bay in order to move forward into more areas of the kingdom is to use his large scythe against his allies, as they are just as vulnerable to this attack as Alice.

Eventually you'll be able to defeat him, but I don't want to spoil his demise :)

Comment: What a way to die. :)..

Answer (score -1):

Dodge until you go through the maze. You'll find the eat me cake and Alice will step on him. Try not to get frustrated. Good luck.